# Is there any way to handle authentication alert using selenium without any OS tool like autoIT and robot

Tags: java, selenium

I am facing authentication pop up for a webpage:
for now take it as example,
https://test.com

what I have tried

```
https://username:password@test.com
```

but it is not logging in. the pop again comes and asks for login credentials.

**Issue**
I have to run the script headless so I don't want to use AutoIT, Robot, is there other way to handle this?

Comment: Are you sure, If URL is correct?

Comment: Did you check the credentials? are you sure you're getting HTTP Basic Auth popup and not something else?

Answer (score 0):

This is called Basic Authorization and solved by injecting header with authentication data. What you have tried used to work before but then it was considered insecure so such form of authentication is no more supported.

Selenium does not have native mechanism to address that but you can [use BrowserMob-Proxy](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization) in order to add header data from your Selenium test.